# Display dropdown list of comboBox when clicked/entered?

Tags: c#

How to display the dropdown list of a comboBox when I click/enter it?

```
private void comboBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

or

```
private void comboBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have not mentioned if this is a Web/Windows/WPF so I am suggesting to do this

Winforms

```
((ComboBox)sender).DroppedDown = true;
```

WPF

```
((ComboBox)sender).IsDropDownOpen = true;
```